# Need to strip off leading zeros in excel

Tags: excel

I downloaded banking account data in a csv file with fields separated by commas. I converted it into excel file succesfully, except by the fact that I couldn't remove the leading zeros en the numeric  financial fields. Looks like they were pasted as text. I need to strip off the leading zeros from excel cells, and handling the numeric data afterwords. Any help?
By the way:  I found a lot of instructions in the web -including this site- to help doing exactly the opposite, I mean to prevent stripping off leading zeros. That is not what I need. I need the data without leading zeros.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you simply format the fields as numbers (select column, choose Format Cells), it should drop the leading zeros automatically. Have you tried this? What happens?

Comment: Yes, that the first thing I've tried. Nothing happened.  :-(

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix for numbers stored as text: enter the number 1 in a numeric cell (any will do, this is a throwaway). Copy the cell that contains 1. Select all the text numbers you want to convert to numeric. Then do `Edit -> Paste Special -> Multiply`. This will multiply all the data in those cells by 1. Excel will have to convert the text to numbers to do this, and the result will be a simple conversion (since anything times 1 is itself).

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help. Unfortunatelly, I've tried it an it didn't work. Do you think this is related with me working in a Mac (with Excel by Office for Mac, of course)?

Comment: Could be a mac thing, but I don't think so... Did you get errors, or did it just not do anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Value()` function. It converts numeric strings, even with commas.